# Is it possible to edit the supported ciphersuite list in Java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, network-programming, jsse

Is it possible to add ciphersuites to the Java supported ciphersuites list that I could get using: `getSupportedCipherSuites();`

Comment: What class is that method from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. The cipher suites that aren't listed by getSupportedCipherSuites() aren't, err, supported. To add support for them you would have to *implement* them, which takes a lot more than just adding a string to a list.

Why do you think you need this? Ordinarily you shouldn't even be using the supported cipher suites that aren't enabled, let alone adding to them.

Comment: I can `setEnableCiphersuites()`. I want to try some ciphersuites - for testing - that may not be supported by Java.

Comment: @user1810868 You can indeed call setEnabledCipherSuites(), but only with strings that are returned by getSupportedCipherSuites(), and you can't change those, as I have already described.

Comment: @EJP Although, this is an old post, but I disparately need to change the list of supported cipher suites in Java now or find any other programming language that allows me to do so. In your answer you said `To add support for them you would have to implement them`, can you please give me clue how to implement this?